# ActualHeight / ActualWidth

Tags: c#, wpf, actualwidth, actualheight

I'm a little confused with how `ActualWidth` or `ActualHeight` works or how it gets calculated.

```
<Ellipse Height="30" Width="30" Name="rightHand" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Hand.png" />
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

When I use the above code, I get 30 for `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`. but when I programmatically define an Ellipse, the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` are 0, even if I define the (max)height and (max)width attribute - I don't understand how it can be 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` are computed after calling `Measure` and `Arrange`.

The layout system of the WPF calls them automatically after inserting the control into the visual tree (at `DispatcherPriority.Render` IMHO which means they will be queued for execution and the results won't be available instantly).
You can wait for them to become available by queuing an action at `DispatcherPriority.Background`) or by calling the methods manually.

Example for the dispatcher variant:

```
Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();

ellipse.Width = 150;
ellipse.Height = 300;

this.grid.Children.Add(ellipse);

this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}x{1}", ellipse.ActualWidth, ellipse.ActualHeight));
}));
```

Example for the explicit call:

```
Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();

ellipse.Width = 150;
ellipse.Height = 300;

ellipse.Measure(new Size(1000, 1000));
ellipse.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000));

MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}x{1}", ellipse.ActualWidth, ellipse.ActualHeight));
```